# How to solve AttributeError when using torch?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pytorch, python-3.7

I am learning PyTorch and facing a problem. There's always AttributeError when I try to run the code if I use torch.xxx.

Here is my environment:
Windows 10, cuda 10.0.132, Pycharm 2018.3.3, Python 3.7.
I used Anaconda prompt and followed instruction on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ to install PyTorch. Here's the command:
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
pip install torchvision
Then I set the interpreter in PyCharm as the python.exe in the path where the above environment is.

Here are something I tried after error cames out:
change torch.xx to torch._C.xx
pip install pylint
set the interpreter as system interpreter instead of conda interpreter
None of which helps.

this is the code at first:

```
    import torch
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # 画图的模块
    x = torch.unsqueeze(torch.linspace(-2, 2, 500), dim=1)
```

error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/Python/Winter/torch.py", line 1, in <module>
        import torch
      File "E:\Python\Winter\torch.py", line 6, in <module>
        x = torch.unsqueeze(torch.linspace(-2, 2, 500), dim=1)
    AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'unsqueeze'
```

then I tried this:

```
    import torch
    print(torch.FloatTensor([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
```

same error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/Python/Winter/torch.py", line 1, in <module>
        import torch
      File "E:\Python\Winter\torch.py", line 3, in <module>
        print(torch.FloatTensor([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
    AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'FloatTensor'
```

I want to install and use PyTorch correctly.
 Thank you.

Comment: You have a module name clash. Rename your `torch.py` to something else.

Comment: your file name conflict with a module, don't do that